# Journey Builder record removed but continues in Journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have a query that populates a DE (overwrite) that is used for a Journey. If a subscriber is in the middle of this Journey and is removed from the sending DE because they no longer qualify for the query, they still go through the Journey. Is there a way to eject someone from the Journey if they no longer are in the sending DE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once a Contact is injected into an Interaction, you cannot selectively eject that Contact. However are two solutions to achieving this.

For both solutions you need to:

1. Create a duplicate Data Extension of your Event Source DE.
2. Create a duplicate query (that you are currently using to populate your Event Source DE) to overwrite the fields that you created in step 1.
3. Create a new Data Extension with a couple of fields; CustomerKey and EjectFromJourney. Make the 'EjectFromJourney' field boolean and to default to 'false'.
4. Create a new Query Activity with the Update type set to 'Update'. Write the query to compare your Event Source DE against the DE that you created in step 1. You only want to select customers that don't appear in the Event Source DE. Set the 'EjectFromJourney' field to `1` (true) for these records
5. Set up an automation to:

   - step 1: run your existing query that overwrites Event Source DE
   - step 2: runs query created in step 4
   - step 3: run query created in step 2
6. Add a 1:1 relationship to the DE created in Step 3 to your Attribute Group in Contact Builder's Data Designer.

What the automation in step 5 essentially does is creates a Data Extension containing a list of customers that you want to eject from the journey, by comparing the records from the previous time the query was run to the current records in your Event Source.

Now you have done this, you have a couple of options:

1. Before each email Activity in your Interaction, add a Decision Split Activity to check whether the value of the 'EjectFromJourney' field is 'true' for the Contact, (if this is true, then route them to an orphan branch) **or**
2. Create a Goal for the Interaction and set the same criteria as mentioned above for the Decision Split Activity, then enable the Exit Option 'When the customer reaches this Goal, they will exit the Interaction'.

The second option is essentially a 'reverse Goal' and isn't really appropriate if you want to set a measurable Goal to monitor the performance of your Interaction. However, it will mean that you don't need to include multiple Decision Split Activities in your Journey to evaluate the Contact as they are moving through it.

I have previously asked the Journey Builder product team for the feature to selectively eject individual Contacts from an Interaction, it would be great to see this in a future release!

Comment: As I suspected, ugh. My client would actually like to have a real goal for this interaction, so I'll likely have to put a decision split before each communication. Thanks as always Eliot!

Comment: This still is the way to go, right? I mean, even tho it has been nearly 2 years from the answer... I haven't found any other way.

Comment: You still can't eject a contact from a Journey, but you could suppress them from receiving emails by using an Exclusion Script.